# netty idlestatehandler invalid delay time

Tags: java, netty

i have an example that uses java 1.8 and netty 4.1.30.Final version IdleStateHandler to output the current time when no action is taken for 400 milliseconds. However, the current time is output at intervals of 2 seconds instead of 400 milliseconds.

here is my example code

**Client.java**

```
public void connect() {
    EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new OioEventLoopGroup();
    try {
        Bootstrap bootstrap = new Bootstrap();
        bootstrap.group(workerGroup)
                .channel(RxtxChannel.class)
                .option(RxtxChannelOption.BAUD_RATE, 38400)
                .option(RxtxChannelOption.DATA_BITS, RxtxChannelConfig.Databits.DATABITS_8)
                .option(RxtxChannelOption.PARITY_BIT, RxtxChannelConfig.Paritybit.NONE)
                .option(RxtxChannelOption.STOP_BITS, RxtxChannelConfig.Stopbits.STOPBITS_1)
                .handler(new ExampleChannelInitializer());
        this.channel = bootstrap.connect(new RxtxDeviceAddress("COM1")).sync().channel();
        this.channel.closeFuture().addListener(f -> {
            workerGroup.shutdownGracefully();
        });

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new ConnectionException(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
```

**ExampleChannelInitializer.java**

```
@Override
protected void initChannel(RxtxChannel ch) throws Exception {
    ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();

    pipeline.addLast(new IdleStateHandler(0, 0, 400, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
    pipeline.addLast(new ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void userEventTriggered(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object evt) throws Exception {
            System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now());
        }
    });
}
```

**Console**

2018-10-30T10:42:02.762

2018-10-30T10:42:04.789

2018-10-30T10:42:06.818

2018-10-30T10:42:08.844

2018-10-30T10:42:10.871

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is unfortunately just a matter of fact how the OIO transport and so RXTX work under the hood. You can make these more "precise" by using `RxtxChannelOption.READ_TIMEOUT` and `RxtxChannelOption.WAIT_TIME` and set these to some smaller value.

Comment: thank! it works very fast!!! let's see more about how RXTX works! thank you very much.